# oracle - group by - no aggregation

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, analytic-functions

I have an oracle table , where ref_id is the flag field is the type of data and ORN is the order of data in each ref_id :

```
ref_id   data    ORN   flag
  1       100     0     0
  1       200     1     0
  1       300     2     0
  1       400     3     0
  1       110     0     1
  1       210     1     1
  1       150     0     2
  1       250     1     2
  1       350     2     2
  1       450     3     2
  2       500     0     0
  2       600     1     0
  2       700     2     0
  2       800     3     0
  2       120     0     1
  2       220     1     1
  2       320     1     1
  2       420     1     1
  2       170     0     2
  2       270     1     2
  2       370     2     2
  2       470     3     2
```

I need to group the data in a way to get last data in flag 0 and last data in flag 2 for each ref_id

so the new table will be something like this:

```
ref_id    data_1    data_2
  1        400       450
  2        800       470
```

any hint how to accomplish this without using loops?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the analytical function and group by  as follows:

```
SELECT REF_ID, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN FLAG = 0 THEN DATA END) AS DATA_0,
       MAX(CASE WHEN FLAG = 2 THEN DATA END) AS DATA_2
FROM
(
  SELECT REF_ID, DATA, ORN, FLAG,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY REF_ID, FLAG ORDER BY ORN DESC) AS RN
  FROM YOUR_TABLE 
  WHERE FLAG IN (0,2)
)
WHERE RN = 1
GROUP BY REF_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively use a *two step approach*, first (in the `CTE`) select only the values of the `DATA` column that corresponds to the *last `ORN` within the `REF_ID`*

Note that is case the `ORN`is not unique you may get more than one row potentially with different values.

In the next step simple aggregate on `REF_ID`, I'm using `max` function, i.e. this will get that *highest value of `DATA` in case of ties.*

In case the combination of `REF_ID` and `ORN` is unique (primary key) you may use `MIN` and `MAX` interchangeable, but it is good to know that they will provide *diffremt result* if dups are allowed.

```
with agg as (
select 
 REF_ID,FLAG, DATA, ORN,
 case when flag = 0  and ORN = max(ORN) over (partition by REF_ID, FLAG) then data end as data_0,
 case when flag = 2  and ORN = max(ORN) over (partition by REF_ID, FLAG) then data end as data_2
from tab
)
select  REF_ID, 
 max(data_0) as data_0,
 max(data_2) as data_2
from agg
group by REF_ID
order by 1;
```

Here the result of the CTE

```
    REF_ID       FLAG       DATA        ORN     DATA_0     DATA_2
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          0        100          0                      
         1          0        200          1                      
         1          0        300          2                      
         1          0        400          3        400           
         1          1        110          0                      
         1          1        210          1                      
         1          2        150          0                      
         1          2        250          1                      
         1          2        350          2                      
         1          2        450          3                   450
...
```

and the result of the final query

```
    REF_ID     DATA_0     DATA_2
---------- ---------- ----------
         1        400        450
         2        800        470
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the aggregate functions (FIRST/LAST) for the purpose.

`https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions074.htm#SQLRF00641`

`https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions095.htm#SQLRF00653`.

```
with t (ref_id,data,ORN,flag) as (
select   1,       100,     0,     0 from dual union all
select   1,       200,     1,     0 from dual union all
select   1,       300,     2,     0 from dual union all
select   1,       400,     3,     0 from dual union all
select   1,       110,     0,     1 from dual union all
select   1,       210,     1,     1 from dual union all
select   1,       150,     0,     2 from dual union all
select   1,       250,     1,     2 from dual union all
select   1,       350,     2,     2 from dual union all
select   1,       450,     3,     2 from dual union all

select   2,       500,     0,     0 from dual union all
select   2,       600,     1,     0 from dual union all
select   2,       700,     2,     0 from dual union all
select   2,       800,     3,     0 from dual union all
select   2,       120,     0,     1 from dual union all
select   2,       220,     1,     1 from dual union all
select   2,       320,     1,     1 from dual union all
select   2,       420,     1,     1 from dual union all
select   2,       170,     0,     2 from dual union all
select   2,       270,     1,     2 from dual union all
select   2,       370,     2,     2 from dual union all
select   2,       470,     3,     2 from dual 
)
select 
  ref_id
, max(decode(flag, 0, data)) keep (dense_rank last order by decode(flag, 0, 100, 50), orn ) x
, max(decode(flag, 2, data)) keep (dense_rank last order by decode(flag, 2, 100, 50), orn ) y 
-- or
, min(decode(flag, 0, data)) keep (dense_rank first order by decode(flag, 0, 50, 100), orn desc) xx
, min(decode(flag, 2, data)) keep (dense_rank first order by decode(flag, 2, 50, 100), orn desc) yy

from t
group by ref_id

    REF_ID          X          Y         XX         YY
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1        400        450        400        450
         2        800        470        800        470
```

Comment: I had the same idea, but noticed then that this reports a wrong value belonging to another flag in case a flag (0 or 2)  is completely missing from the data set. (Remove all `ref_id = 1, flag = 2` to see what I mean.)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, thank you. updated the statement to handle the case you pointed out.